# Find a file with the extension .csv in a directory matching a pattern

Tags: shell, shell-script, find, filenames, wildcards

I have a folder in which I have many subfolders.

The Root folder name is allCSV and sub foldername is will be like `a_date(s), b_date(s), c_date(s) ...`

I want a file which is in a_date(s) and ends with `.csv`.

I tried with:

```
find ../ -name '[a_]*' -a -name '*[.csv]'
```

But it is showing all the files ending with `.csv`

Comment: @VP:try (http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) .A good software to search items in a folder _including in the folder contents_.

Comment: Why not `find allCSV/a_date -type f -name '*.csv'`?

Comment: @cuonglm I dont want to search in a particular date. the folder a_date, a_date2 may have the CSV file, while a_date3 may not have.

Comment: `find .. -path '*/a_*/*' -name '*.csv'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you Very much. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern `[a_]*` matches names that start with either of the characters `a` or `_`. The pattern `*[.csv]` matches names that end with one of the characters `.`, `c`, `s` or `v`. To match names that start with `a_`, use `-name 'a_*'`. To match names that end with `.csv`, use `-name '*.csv'`.

`find ../ -name 'a_*' -a -name '*.csv'` or equivalently `find ../ -name 'a_*.csv'` matches files whose name starts with `a_` and ends with `.csv`. This does not filter on the directories traversed to reach the file.

If the files are in subdirectories of the parent directory (e.g. `../a_foo/wibble.csv`), you don't need `find`: the `find` command is only useful to search directory trees recursively. You can use `echo` or `ls`:

```
ls ../a_*/*.csv
```

If the files can be in subdirectories below the `a_*` directories (e.g. `../a_foo/wibble.csv` or `../a_foo/bar/wibble.csv` but not `../qux/a_foo/wibble.csv`), then call `find` and tell it to search the `a_*` directories.

```
find ../a_* -name '*.csv'
```

Alternatively, instead of using `find`, you can use the [`**`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) wildcard to search in subdirectories recursively. In ksh93, you need to enable this pattern with `set -o globstar` first. In bash, you need to enable this pattern with `shopt -s globstar` first. In zsh, this pattern is enabled by default. Other shells such as plain sh don't have `**`.

```
ls ../a_*/**/*.csv
```

If the `a_*` directories can themselves be at any depth below the parent directory, you can either use `find -path` or `**`:

```
find .. -path '*/a_*/*.csv'
ls ../**/a_*/**/*.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. If you just want to list the files, you can use `ls`:

```
ls a_date\(s\)/*csv
```

Or, with `find`:

```
find .. -path '*a_date*/*csv' 
find ../allCSVs/a_date\(s\)/ -name '*csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) that helps you to search any document type and also restrict your search to a particular folder as shown below.

**Simple Search**
[image: Simple Search]

**Advanced Search(To restrict search to a particular folder)**
[image: Restricting Search]

Comment: I would like to use using command line.

Comment: @VP7:If you have installed Recoll you would have noticed that it could be run from the command prompt too.

Comment: It will be helpful if I can achieve with default vim commands

Comment: @VP7:Do you mean you couldn't install Recoll?